# Is there a memory leak in this C++ move constructor?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, move-constructor

In Stroustrups The C++ Programming Language Fourth Edition, on page 76, there is example of move constructor use.

The class is defined like this:

```
class Vector { 
private: 
  double∗ elem; // elem points to an array of sz doubles 
  int sz; 
public: 
  Vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} 
  { for (int i=0; i!=s; ++i) elem[i]=0; // initialize elements } 

  ~Vector() { delete[] elem; } // destructor: release resources 
  Vector(const Vector& a); // copy constructor 
  Vector& operator=(const Vector& a); // copy assignment 
  Vector(Vector&& a); // move constructor 
  Vector& operator=(Vector&& a); // move assignment 

  double& operator[](int i); 
  const double& operator[](int i) const; 
  int size() const; 
};
```

The move constructor is defined:

```
Vector::Vector(Vector&& a) :elem{a.elem}, // "grab the elements" from a 
  sz{a.sz} 
{ 
  a.elem = nullptr; // now a has no elements 
  a.sz = 0; 
}
```

Example execution which, I think, will cause memory leak:

```
Vector f() 
{ 
  Vector x(1000); 
  Vector y(1000); 
  Vector z(1000); 
  // ... 
  z=x; //we get a copy 
  y = std::move(x); // we get a move 
  // ... 
  return z; //we get a move 
};
```

It seems that such move operation will cause memory leak, because y had been allocated 1000 elements in

```
Vector y(1000);
```

and simple pointer re-assignment at line y = std::move(x); would leave these initial 1000 ints pointed by y left on its own. I assume, the move constructor has to have extra line of code to de-allocate pointer 'elem' before moving.

Comment: What you have shown is a move copy constructor. How is the move assignment implemented, because thats what gets called in your example.

Comment: Unrelated, I find it  odd that you move the `elem` member, but seem to ignore moving the `sz` member. If it was important enough to zero out in the source of the move, it is probably important enough to retain in your move target. There is a dangling `,` after that member initializer, so perhaps you just neglected to paste *all* of your code for that constructor (for whatever reason).

Comment: @WhozCraig It looks like it does but the OP used a comment and broke the formatting.  look at `elem{a.elem}, // "grab the elements" from a z{a.sz} `.

Comment: @NathanOliver outstanding.

Comment: yes, I corrected originally wrong-pasted code, see the code above.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the move constructor is implemented properly, no. The line you are refering to invokes move assignment, not constructor, because `z` already exists.

Comment: Yes, agree, this is move assignment: y = std::move(x);, not the constructor.
In the book they did not show it, just mentioned that move assignment is defined similarly. 
But, in the move assignment definition, as I understand, we would need to deallocate elem, right? Something like this?

    Vector& Vector::operator=(Vector&& a)
    { 
      delete[] elem;
      elem = a.elem;
      sz = a.sz;
      a.elem = nullptr; // now a has no elements 
      a.sz = 0; 
    }

Comment: @AndreyChertov Either that, or swap your `elem` ptr and `sz` with the other `Vector`, taking its data and letting it to take care of your own. If you have doubts about the move assignment implementation, update your question with it -- I don't own the book.

Comment: Nice! Swapping looks more elegant than deleting[] inside the move assignment. Good call. This way every object will take care of itself when going out of the scope. In this case, nullptr should not be used.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a memory leak in this C++ move constructor?

No.

> Example execution which, I think, will cause memory leak:

The shown execution calls move assignment, not move constructor.

> I assume, the move constructor has to have extra line of code to de-allocate pointer 'elem' before moving.

It does not need to, because the pointer of the newly constructed object can not have pointed to any allocated memory before it was initialized with the value of the pointer from the move argument.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, agree, this is move assignment: y = std::move(x);, not the constructor.
In the book they did not show it, just mentioned that move assignment is defined similarly. 
But, in the move assignment definition, as I understand, we would need to deallocate elem, right? Something like this.

```
Vector& Vector::operator=(Vector&& a)
{ 
  delete[] elem;
  elem = a.elem;
  sz = a.sz;
  a.elem = nullptr; // now a has no elements 
  a.sz = 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> and simple pointer re-assignment at line y = std::move(x); would leave
>   these initial 1000 ints pointed by y left on its own.

The address of the pointer to double is copied over to the new object (y) and the old object (x) has it's pointer set to nullptr. (It's happening in the move assignment method not shown)

> I assume, the move constructor has to have extra line of code to
>   de-allocate pointer 'elem' before moving.

No deallocation needed here. The pointer is just 'moved' during assignment (it would also be moved during move construction). Cleanup of the double pointer should be handled by the destructor. In the case of x, the destructor would eventually fire on the nullptr.  delete[] on a nullptr is a noop. see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/

The doubles allocated in y would however need to be cleaned out during the move assignment as pointed out.

Comment: "The pointer is just 'moved' during assignment...Cleanup of the double pointer should be handled by the destructor."

   If we do not clean up in the move assignment, the initially allocated 1000 of initial y would leak. The destructor will delete[] only the 1000 initially allocated in x and which were moved to y. But the ones allocated in y need to be deleted[] before elem = a.elem;

Comment: ah ic now. Good call. Yes, the ones in Y need to be cleared out before transfer.